# Display a modal after 30 seconds and reload page

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I have an ajax call and in its success function, I am displaying a modal and refreshing the page after 3 seconds.

Right now, after my first modal shows, it shows the second modal right after and immediately loads the page in 6 seconds which isn't what I want. I'd appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are 2 parts to your question:

First, the fact that the second modal shows right after the first one. This comes from the fact that you set a 5000ms timer to show the second modal at the bottom of your code. If you want to show the second modal only after reload, you cannot put this code there.

The second part is how to display the second modal after 30s AFTER RELOAD of the page. There are several ways to achieve this, depending on the experience you want to give to your user. One option would be to use cookies, to check if the user has already seen the first modal. You can find more details here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie#example_3_do_something_only_once

Here's an example of what you could do:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "db.php",
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    data: formData,
    success: function (result) {
        result = JSON.parse(result);

        if (result.validity === "valid emails") {
            resetInputs();

            if (!document.cookie.split('; ').find(row => row.startsWith('firstModalShown'))) {
                document.cookie = "firstModalShown=true; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT; Secure";

                $('#alertModalUploaded').modal('show');

                setTimeout(function () {
                    var formDataS3 = new FormData($('#files')[0]);
                    formDataS3.append('file', fileObj);
                    formDataS3.append('dirName', result.dirName);

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/fileToS3.php",
                        cache: false,
                        processData: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        data: formDataS3,
                        success: function (res) {
                            res = JSON.parse(res);
                            if (res === "Upload failed") {
                                $('#alertModalFile').modal({ show: true });
                                document.getElementById('userFile').value = null;
                                enableBtn();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    window.location.reload(1);
                }, 6000);
            }
            else if (!document.cookie.split('; ').find(row => row.startsWith('secondModalShown'))) {
                document.cookie = "secondModalShown=true; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT; Secure";

                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('#alertReload').modal({ show: true });
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        window.location.reload(1);
                    }, 5000);
                }, 30000);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Of course I don't know how this code is called so you may have to reorganize it to make it work the way you want!